# fit adobe air app on smaller screen

Tags: flash, air

I inherited an Adobe Air project where almost all the UI is created via action script code.  The projects dimensions are 1920x1080.

When deploy this app to my first generation Galaxy Note 10.1, parts of the screen is cut off because my tablet has a resolution smaller than 1920x1080.  Is there a way to publish the app so that it fits in my tablet's screen without being cut off?

I notice in the action script code that there are a lot of hard-coded dimensions for positioning UI elements.   Changing the values of all these coordinates would be a lot of work, so I'd prefer not to do it. I'd prefer the app to just scale to fit most devices.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The app should currently be set to not scale.  Set stage.Scalemode in the code.  Scaling makes things blurry like incorrectly sizing a jpg.  Compare screenshots of both no_scale and scaling, don't just try to eyeball it.  Scaling can also cause performance problems (can crash games) so animations and scrolling could get affected.  Use Scout to compare the differences in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your screen aspect doesn't change too much (like not switching landscape to portrait) this is an easy fix:

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;

somethings will get stretched.. but I've used it a lot :D